# Is there a way to dynamically fit images to a frame in reportlab using platypus?

Tags: python, reportlab, platypus

I'm using reportlab to generate some pdfs. I need to append some images. The old script relied on a deprecated library to add pdf versions of these images to new pdf, but I think I should be able to add them as pngs like so:

```
doc = SimpleDocTemplate("GBD Country Report - " + country_name + ".pdf",
                            pagesize=letter,
                            rightMargin=0.25 * inch, leftMargin=0.25 * inch,
                            topMargin=0.75 * inch, bottomMargin=0.25 * inch)
 elements = []
 elements.append(Image(data_dir + 'figure1.png'), width=1, height=1)
 doc.build(elements)
```

However, when I do this I get this error: `reportlab.platypus.doctemplate.LayoutError: Flowable <Image at 0x10bd6ae10 frame=cod filename=.../figure1.png>(28.346456692913385 x 612.0) too large on page 1 in frame 'cod'(475.2 x 90.0*) of template 'FirstPage'`. I've tried adding changing the width and height args multiple times, but it doesn't help. Is there any way I can dynamically modify the width and the height of the chart images so that they fit in the frame/template?

Answer (score 0):

This is quite an old question. But I couldn't find a solution I was happy with, so I thought I would share my gross custom solution. Please note, you will need to exchange letter for whatever template size object you import. You will also need to change the numbers 80 and 300 to suit your own margin preferences, but I found these effective.

```
# New dependency
import matplotlib.image as img

# Inferred dependencies of OP
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Image

# Read in image as array to assess dimensions
image = img.imread(pic_fp)

# Compare the reportlab template size object with the image to understand
# which dimension needs to be changed the most to make it fit on a page
width_is_restriction = (image.shape[0] / letter[1]) < (image.shape[1] / letter[0])

if width_is_restriction:
    new_width = letter[0] - 80 # Add small margins to sides
    new_height = image.shape[0] * (new_width / image.shape[1])

else:
    new_height = letter[1] - 300 # Add margins for titles, header etc
    new_width = image.shape[1] * (new_height / image.shape[0])

img_flowable = Image(pic_fp, width=new_width, height=new_height),
```

Answer (score -3):

Simply multiply your width and height by your desired unit, i.e. (width =1*inch, height=1*inch).

Units of measurement can be brought in with: 
from reportlab.lib.units import inch.

Good luck!